# reason for including header files in Makefile pre-requisites

Tags: c++, makefile

I am going through [This](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile) make tutorial. Here, they mentioned header files in pre-requisites. Is this really necessary? I ran the same code without headers and it worked. For example, i have the following code

`funcs.h`

```
#ifndef FUNCS_H
#define FUNCS_H

int add(int a, int b);

#endif
```

`funcs.cpp`

```
#include "funcs.h"

int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include "funcs.h"


int main(){
    std::cout << add(1,2) << "\n";
}
```

`Makefile`

```
add : main.o funcs.o
    g++ -o add main.o funcs.o

main.o : main.cpp funcs.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

funcs.o : funcs.cpp funcs.h
    g++ -c funcs.cpp

clean :
    rm add main.o funcs.o
```

Even when i remove header files from `funcs.o` and `main.o` targets, it still works. So, is there any other reason why one would put header files?

Comment: Arent you confusing 'making' and 'running' ?

Comment: i am sorry. what do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file names after a colon in the makefile are the dependencies of the target. Make checks them, and if any of the dependencies is newer than the target, the target is re-built, using the command on the next line.

So, of course you can still build and run when you remove the headerfiles from the dependencies, but if you would change something only in a headerfile, make will not re-build all your targets properly.

Answer (score 2):

@Rene has the correct answer to your question, but I thought I'd point out that the best practice is to have automatic header dependency generation.  Otherwise, medium and large build systems become very hard to maintain.  If, for example a third party added the line `#include "foo.h"` into your main.cpp, then there is a good chance the makefile would not get updated to match.   If foo.h depended on another header it gets even more complicated..   A better practice is to have the makefile and compiler automatically generate the dependencies.   The following would build your example a bit more cleanly:

```
SRCS := main.cpp funcs.cpp
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)

DEPFLAGS = -MMD -MP

add: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

$(OBJS) : %.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) -c $<

-include $(DEPS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEPS) add
```

Since you're running a tutorial, I will assume that you are new to make, so I'll walk through this a bit:

First, you set the variable `SRCS` to be all the sources required.  Then `OBJS` is set based on `SRCS` using pattern substitutions (described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html))

Once this is done, the target `add` becomes dependent on all `OBJS`.  I used [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) `$@` and `$^` in the linking recipe to represent the target, and a list of all dependencies respectively.   This is again to avoid someone updating one thing, and forgetting to update somewhere else.

A [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) is then used to generate the any of the files in `$(OBJS)`.  Here's where the fun comes in.   There are some extra flags passed into the compiler -- `$(DEPFLAGS)` (this assumes a GCC compiler).   The flags passed in are `-MMD`, which tells make to build the dependencies, and `-MP` which protects against a corner case where header files are deleted between builds.  These will cause the compiler to generate a .d file along with the .o file.   See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) for details on what exactly the flags do.   The .d file will look like this:

```
 main.o: main.cpp funcs.h

 funcs.h:
```

Notice that this is a mini-makefile, that only lists dependencies.   It can thus be included from the main makefile, which is what happens on the next line.   You get:

```
 -include $(DEPS)
```

The `-` in front is important here -- it means that if the .d file does not exist (which it will not in the first iteration), then don't include it.   If it does exist, then read the file in as if it were typed in inline.   Notice that in the first iteration, the .o file will also not exist, so the target will be built regardless, and so listing the dependencies is moot.   In subsequent iterations, your target will read in the dependencies that the currently built version is dependent on, an if any of those changed, it will know the current object is out of date, and rebuild it.

Finally, in your clean, you need to wipe out the generated dependencies along with the generated objects.

If you want to go in even deeper, you can reference [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/), which has a few tricks that I didn't mention (such as keeping the deps in their own directory, etc).

Comment: i am not joking.. while reading that makefile.. i was literally thinking wtf are these symbols. Thank you so much. Now, i understand these

Comment: How long have you been working with make? Also, do you think.. one should dig deeper into make as i can also use cmake to generate these right?

Comment: I can't comment on cmake, as I've never used it.   I have used make for a while though.   I think with make, if you understand the above, you're pretty close to understanding all makefiles...  (an `@` symbol at the beginning of a recipe, and `.PHONY` are the main two things I would still suggest looking up).   After that, it's not to bad.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much.